# How to select records where field is missing from an Azure Storage Table?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm attempting to process records that were inserted into Azure Table Storage prior to the addition of a new attribute. The [LINQ support is limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service) and I'm struggling to get this to work.

How would one use LINQ (or another method) to filter an Azure Table to just records missing an attribute for a given entity?

### Sample Code

I'm writing it in an Azure Function, and the row count here returns 0, when attempting a default value for the field.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, IQueryable<ts_webhit> inTable, TraceWriter log)
{
    IEnumerable<ts_webhit> recs = (from r in inTable
                                   where "2016-11-21 12:45" == r.PartitionKey
                                   &&    ""                 == r.Category  //The filter I need to run
                                   select r);
    log.Info($"{recs.Count()}");
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, recs.ToList());
}

public class ts_webhit : TableEntity
{

    public string Category { get; set; } = ""; //Attempting a default value

}
```

### Some candidate filters that didn't work

- `r.Category is nothing` generates a compilation error
- `String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Category)` returns that it's not supported
- `r.Category == null` returns a bad request
- `!r.Category.HasValue` generates a compilation error as it's a string

Comment: Looks like there's a prior question, tho (IMO) lower quality! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913668/azure-table-storage-where-clause-on-column-that-may-not-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the property did not exist on the entity when it was written to table storage than that column will not exist on the table hence any comparison you make in your query - including the comparison with an empty string - will fail and you will get an empty response.

Comment: Is there any way to check whether an attribute is missing then or is this just an impossible task as it stands?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way you can do the filtering on the table service side for properties that do not exist on the already written entities but you can of course filter those entities out on the client side after you retrieve all entities from that partition.