# Not Loading all columns from Azure Table Storage Source in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Azure Table Storage to Csv file using "Copy Activity" in Azure Data Factory. But few columns are not loading.

In Azure Table Source Dataset Preview I'm not able to see all columns. Those columns have Null data for first 400 rows. If i have data for all fields in first 11 rows then i am able to see and load all fields data. 
But in my case for few fields we have null data for few rows so how to load all columns data?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points

1. In  preview we always show a few of records  and not all .
2. The table storage is not a schema based storage and the null are treated differently here . I think this  \
   [Querying azure table storage for null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228460/querying-azure-table-storage-for-null-values)

   will help you understand more .

I am pretty confident that when you run the copy activity it will copy all the records to the sink , even if you do see few in the preview .

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem "Not Loading all columns from Azure Table Storage Source in Azure Data Factory". I think it may be a bug of Azure Data Factory.